# Consolidating functions for cleaner code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function, mfc, parameters

Don't be turned off by the length...I don't think it's too difficult of a problem.

**Language:** C++

**Development Environment:** Microsoft Visual C++

**Libraries Used:** MFC

**Problem:** I am creating a large preference dialog with several "pages". Many of them require the user to specify a file path. Right now, the user will click on the button, and it will jump to OnCommand(). This will verify that the command was from a button, then jump to the Browse() function where it will figure out which button was pressed. Finally, it will call FileDialog() which will launch a file chooser, then return the file path, assign it to the correct variable, and append it to the correct edit control.

I am trying to consolidate all of these "open file" buttons into one class or function, but I'm not sure the best way to approach it. I would love for it to be clean so that I don't have to feed it specific IDs (2001, 2002, ...).

Right now, these three functions (below) are in each of my files...this is messy and unnecessary. I want to have a single file called **OpenFile.cpp** or something that contains the necessary functions to handle opening a file, and *appending the chosen path to the correct text box within the correct dialog.*

```
BOOL FSC_3DPersp::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
  {
    Browse(LOWORD(wParam));
    return TRUE;
  }
return CWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

//

```
CString OpenFile::FileDialog(CWnd* wnd, int uiID) // dialog from which the call came and the ID of the edit control where the path is going
{
  CFileDialog dlg(
      TRUE // Open = TRUE, Save = FALSE
    , NULL //filename extension
    , "" // initial filename
    , OFN_ENABLESIZING|OFN_EXPLORER|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST // flags
    , "" // filter
    , wnd // parent window
  ); 

  if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
  {
    CEdit *Display;
    CString path = dlg.GetPathName();
    Display = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(uiID));
    Display->SetWindowText((LPCTSTR)path);
    return path;
  }
}
```

//

```
void FSC_3DPersp::Browse(UINT uiID)
{
 switch(uiID)
 {
 case IDC_BUTTON1: 
    m_strPersTexture = FileDialog(this, 2004);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON2:
    m_strSkyFront = FileDialog(this, 2005);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON3:
    m_strSkyRight = FileDialog(this, 2006);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON4:
    m_strSkyBack = FileDialog(this, 2007);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON5:
    m_strSkyTop = FileDialog(this, 2008);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON6:
    m_strSkyLeft = FileDialog(this, 2009);
    break;
 case IDC_BUTTON7:
    m_strSkyBottom = FileDialog(this, 2010);
    break;
 }
}
```

---

**Header File Definitions:**

```
afx_msg CString FileDialog(CWnd* wnd, int uiID);
afx_msg void Browse(UINT uiID);
virtual BOOL OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

So how can I adjust the parameters to put all three of them into one file, and how would I reference them? If I did this, I feel like I need to add an additional parameter to the OnCommand() function, but I don't think I can do that.

Thank you in advance for the help!

~ Jon

Comment: How do the signatures of the other definitions look like? If they are the same, merging them all into a single unit should not impose a lot of problems.

Comment: @phresnel Do you mean the definitions in the header files? I'll add them above.

Comment: I mean, if your "function-redefinitions" in all your compilation units are the same, it shouldn't be a big problem to merge them.

Comment: @phresnel They should all be the same. I'm just not sure how to pass the ID of the dialog from which the "call" came to know which button was pressed, and thus, which edit control needs to be appended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using [CMFCEditBrowseCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx) or [COXBrowseFileEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_GUI.aspx#File_Picker) (or other similar classes) instead of normal edit controls?
These classes create edit boxes with a "browse" button which, when clicked, automatically opens a file selection dialog and set the selected file as the edit control text.

Comment: Gah, this is so much easier and will save a lot of time I think. Thank you!

Comment: Or implement your own CWnd-derived control with a `CEdit` and `CButton` that exposes a `GetFileName()` method.